# Set Project-Icon in Visual Studio with relative path

Tags: visual-studio

In my Visual Stuido 2019 Project, I have a folder for my Images. (/Images/)

Now I wanted to use one of those images (EuroCoins.ico) as the icon for the .exe of the Project. (under Project Settings -> Symbol)

There i selected .ico, which is in a child dir of the Project. But instead of using a relative path to the existing image, VS creates a copy in the root dir of the project.

[image]

Is there a way that VS uses the image in the given path (/Images/EuroCoins.ico) instead of creating a copy (/EuroCoins.ico)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem:

First, you set the Icon the normal way. This will create a copy in the Project root. (`Icon.ico`)

You now can drag and drop the Icon to the required folder inside VisualStudio. This will automatically cause VisualStudio to update the Icon-Path accordingly. (`Images\Icon.ico`)

[image]